# Lazy loading routes into separate Vue instances

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

In our app, we split up each "product" into its own Vue instance when the user navigates to them. Kind of like this:

```js
var initialiseApp1 = function() {
    app = new Vue({
        el: '#app',
        router: App1Router,
        store: Store,
        render: h => h(Tracker),
        i18n,
    })
}

var pathname = window.location.pathname
var productName = pathname.substr(1, pathname.length).toLowerCase()

if (productName === 'app1') {
    initialiseApp1()
}
```

We'd like to code-split the products into their own chunks, so they only load when needed. To start, we'd like to lazy load the routes, but using our current method of creating each product as its own Vue instance. I can't seem to get the normal method like this to work:

```js
const App1Router= () => import('./App1Router.vue')
```

How can we accomplish this?

Comment: I wonder cant you handle this within vue router? If I remember correctly vuerouter plugin checks for router option on beforecreate over inheritance from $parent thus I guess one should be able to override at runtime - never tried though...